# R code mcmcplots function

Tags: r, plot, mcmc

Is there a way to make the R `mcmcplot()` function not open a browser when it's called? I need to run my R code on a cluster and if `mcmcplot()` tries to open a browser, it will puke.

Can the output be dumped to a file maybe?

Comment: Could `try(mcmcplot())` solve your problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That function writes everything to a file and also opens it in a browser. If you dont want to open the browser I would recommend editing the function to pass whether or not you want to open in a browser as an argument. You can retreive the function by just typing its name without any parenthesis.

`mcmcplot`

then copy that output to a editor and at the beginning change the name of the function and add teh argument:

```
mcmcplotnew=function (mcmcout, parms = NULL, regex = NULL, random = NULL, 
    leaf.marker = "[\\[_]", dir = tempdir(), filename = "MCMCoutput", 
    extension = "html", title = NULL, heading = title, col = NULL, 
    lty = 1, xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL, style = c("gray", "plain"), 
    greek = FALSE,ShouldIPlotinbrowser=T)   #new argument here
```

then there are much more parts of the function

then at the end there is

```
    cat("\r", rep(" ", getOption("width")), "\r", sep = "")
    cat("\n</div>\n</div>\n", file = htmlfile, append = TRUE)
    .html.end(htmlfile)
    full.name.path <- paste("file://", htmlfile, sep = "")
    browseURL(full.name.path)
    invisible(full.name.path)
}
```

Where you have the browsURL line, make it something like:

```
if(ShouldIPlotinbrowser) { browseURL(full.name.path) }
```

Then initialize that function before you run it with:

```
mcmcplotnew(whatever, usual, arguments,then,ShouldIPlotinbrowser=F)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the source](https://gist.github.com/s-mckay-curtis/mcmcplots/blob/master/mcmcplots/R/mcmcplot.R#L72), it seems not. There is an unconditional call to `browseURL()` there. Maybe by making a dummy version of that function which does nothing in your global namespace, it's effect can be avoided.

```
browseURL <- identity
```

This may break other browser activity as well, so after the `mcmcplot` calls, you may want to

```
rm(browseURL)
```

Alternatively, copy all the code from `mcmcplot` except for the `browseURL` line and use that function instead.